# nested count aggregations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I have a type in elasticsearch where each user can post any number of posts(fields being "userid" and "post").Now I need the count of users who posted 0 post,1 post,2 posts and so on....how do I do it? I think it needs some nested aggregations implemented but I don't know how to proceed. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please share the mapping of you index. `GET /index/type/_mapping`

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you shared your mapping and one or two sample documents. Also what kind of query you currently have.

Comment: {
  "ESIndex": {
    "mappings": {
      "user_posts": {
        "properties": {
          "post": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "userid": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is to add a separate field to store the number of posts.

Scripts are not too efficient (values are getting re-evaluated each time a query executes) and you **get the value indexed** properly which makes queries and aggregations very fast. 
Of course you need to be sure you update this count each time you update the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `script` in aggregation:

```
POST index_name/type_name/_search
{
"aggs": {
  "group By Post Count": {
     "terms": {
         "script" : "doc['post'].size()"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Make sure [you enable scriptig](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It does not return any error but it does not return the expected results either